# Efficient way to clean up incoming string fields in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm pulling in data from a flat file into a SQL Server 2008 table.  It contains address information that I'll need to do matching on, so I need to clean up the data some.

I created a table of common abbreviations / terms and their official US Post Office counterpart, and then created a function that can accept an address string and return a cleaned address string using replace and the data from the abbreviations table.

Running an `UPDATE` on the table after import and doing a `SET` on the address fields with the string returned from the function works great but is slow.  I'm fairly new to SQL, is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps during the SSIS import before it's even inserted?

Comment: Have you considered validating the data from official sources as it is entered? Or, for the existing data, just running the list of addresses through a cleaning (or "scrubbing") service before importing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as a lookup or you could put the data into a staging table and then do the clean up on the staging table using an execute sql task and then do the import to the table with a dataflow. I prefer to do it this way for several reasons. First I intially data flow to two tables, One I clean up and one that remains exactly as the file had the data. This way, I have an unedited version fo the data that I can query, an edited version of the data that I can query and the data in the real tables. This helps me research data  import problems. I can easily see if the issue is something due to my clean up or something they sent or something due to how the data is stored (maybe a pk/fk violation or some such which required it to go to an exception table (I also send all records to an exception table if they can't be imported). Further I can fix the clean up process if there is a bug without continually running a long complex timeconsuming process (and without going to the live tables until I am sure it has been fixed). And once the fix is done, typically all I have to do is deploy a new version of the stored proc, not the whole SSIS package. I find this is the best model for being able to reserach and support data imports as they change.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like in this case, in the SSIS package you could do a Lookup to your common terms table, joining on the address, and output the clean address, which would then pass into the destination table.  This would cut out the Update step after loading.

Comment: I haven't tried the Lookup transform, my address field is a full address like "1234 North Elm Street", my terms table has paried entries like |North|N| and |Street|St|.  Could Lookup be used given the nature of the data?